# id3demux support for mp4 and other usecases for id3demux

Tags: plugins, gstreamer

I want to integrate id3demux plugin to our stack. But I had some queries regarding this.

1. Can id3demux support mp4 files as well.? I know it can support mp3.
2. Other than reading the TAG information, is there any other usecase for id3demux.?
3. Can this parsing of TAG be done from any other demux like qtdemux or mpeg2/ts demux. Is id3demux mandatory for this.?

Answer (score 0):

1. No. id3tags are associated with mp3 files. The mp3 file may be inside the mp4. Hence if you demux mp3 from inside the mp4 and give it to the id3demux, yes it will work with it.
2. Not that I can think of.
3. no. it is like saying can mpeg2 decoder decode mpeg4 video. No.